# How can this resampling code be made faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

Suppose I have a matrix:

```
sbt = RandomInteger[{0, 2^16 - 1}, {5202, 3465}];
```

It represents an image and I would like to do "pixel binning" on it, where I take non-overlapping `n x n` square submatrices and replace them with the total of each submatrix. A typical `n` is 8. When the image dimensions aren't divisible by `n` it's okay to discard the last few rows and columns.

Importantly, each resulting pixel is a total, not an average or a bilinear resampling.

My naive function to do this is:

```
imageBin[imagedata_, n_] := With[
  {dims = Reverse@Dimensions[imagedata]},
  Table[
   Total[Flatten[imagedata[[row ;; row + n - 1, col ;; col + n - 1]]]],
   {row, 1, dims[[2]] - n + 1, n},
   {col, 1, dims[[1]] - n + 1, n}
   ]
  ]
```

I have thousands of images to process this way, so I care about making the process fast.

```
Timing[Do[imageBin[sbt, 8];, {10}]]
```

gives about 3.4 seconds on my machine. Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: Are you really processing a generated random image?  You could directly compute a random result based on the expected value of `n*RandomInteger...` for each bin.

Comment: @BenJackson, I'm processing a genuine image. The random one is just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compile the function. For example,

```
imageBinC = Compile[{{imagedata, _Integer, 2}, {n, _Integer}},
   With[{dims = Reverse@Dimensions[imagedata]},
    Table[
     Total[Flatten[
       imagedata[[row ;; row + n - 1, col ;; col + n - 1]]]], {row, 1,
       dims[[2]] - n + 1, n}, {col, 1, dims[[1]] - n + 1, n}
     ]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];


In[11]:= AbsoluteTiming[Do[imageBinC[sbt, 8];, {10}]]

Out[11]= {2.01693, Null}
```

The uncompiled function takes 2.45955 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Well done! I also see a 20% speedup with your technique.

Comment: I think the `Parallelization -> True` is superfluous?

Comment: @blochwave, Yes, I don't think the Parallelization option adds anything.

Answer (score 5):

you can define a function that downsamples in one dimension:

```
downsampleX = Total /@ Partition[#, 10] &;
```

Then call that once on your array and then on each row:

```
downsampleX /@ downsampleX[sbt];
```

Takes about 0.19 s on my PC

Comment: This seems like a great idea and I tried it myself, but it is slightly slower. Ten runs takes 3.5 s compared to the original 3.4 s.

Comment: Interesting, `Partition` can do two both dimensions at once, so you can do simply `Map[Total@Flatten@# &, Partition[sbt, {8, 8}] , {2}];`  However that turns out to be way slower than the other solutions.

Comment: @george2079 Or ``Developer`PartitionMap[Total@*Flatten, sbt, {8,8}]`` (syntactically nicer, but still not fast)

Comment: @george2079 I think it might be unpacking the array?